# What is this plant with thin green stems and little yellow flowers?

Tags: identification

Can someone please identify this plant? I salvaged it from work but have no idea what it is other than it is an outdoor climbing plant, with thin green hardy stems and little yellow flowers produced during wintertime. I live in Birmingham, England.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

It's [Jasmine nudiflorum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jasminum_nudiflorum) - because it's been so mild, that's why its flowering now - in colder years, it still flowers early, but around February/March. Can be hard pruned immediately after flowering is over, but should have flowered stems pruned out anyway at that time. Best tied in to a trellis or support because it's not actually a climber, or planted somewhere you don't mind it flopping and trailing.